# Angular share value between controller

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, share

Hy guys, 
i just want to create a simple Service which allows me to use some values in diffrent Controllers.

But obvious I dont get it what I'm doing wrong.

My Controller:

```
.controller('SettingsCtrl', function ($scope, sharedSettings) {

    $scope.test= sharedSettings.getName();


});
```

My Service:

```
.service('sharedSettings', function () {
    var name = "guguck";
    var verrechnugnMonat = '11';
    var stundenLohn = '';

    return {
        getName: function () {
            return name;
        },
        setName: function (value) {
            name = value;
        },

        getStartVerrechnungsMonat: function (){
            return verrechnungsmonat;
        },

        setStartVerrechnungsMonat: function (value) {
            verrechnugnMonat = value;
        },

        getStundenLohn: function () {
            return stundenLohn;
        },

        setStundenLohn: function (value) {
            stundenLohn = value;
        }

    };
});
```

All I wanna do is getting the value "name" from my Service to my Controller. 
But I always get this error: `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: sharedSettingsProvider <- sharedSettings <- SettingsCtrl`

Comment: Did you call your service before for controller ?

Comment: no, but I think I know where the problem is. My Service is in Services.js and my Controller in Controllers.js. If I but the Service inside the Controller.js it works. In my index.hml is the Services.js declared. But not sure how I can solve this

Comment: The service and the controller are under the same "module"?

Comment: arrrr, thanks shikloshi. I declared the module not correct. OMG, such a stupid misstake

Answer (score 1):

According to the information what you have posted it should work,

Here is the working [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/nMAfJ2uOTebaSizxgeJa?p=preview)